# Setting up desktop RAID on some drives, but not all

Tags: windows-7, windows, raid

I have a Windows 7 desktop with five SATA drives. I would like to make four of the drives into a RAID 5, but leave one (the OS drive) as is.

From the reading I've done, I've found these options, but they don't work for me:

1. Set up a software RAID through Windows (via Disk Management).

   - This doesn't work for me because I need a Linux machine to be able to access this RAID array. I've read that the software RAID is not recognized by other OSs.
2. Set up a RAID using a PCIe RAID card.

   - This doesn't work for me because my desktop currently has no PCIe card slots available.

When I look through the BIOS, I see RAID setup, but I think it's for the whole system (all five drives). Anyway, can I set up a RAID using only some of the drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onboard RAID controllers will let you choose which disks to use in the RAID array.  That is, I havent seen any that havent.

The issue will be making sure you select the right disks.  Many motherboards have multiple SATA connections, some specifically for RAID.  I would check the manual and remove the boot drive, create the RAID, then reattach the boot drive.  You should be good to go.

Also, you could use a PCI RAID card, if you arent worried about speed, just redundancy.

Comment: Thanks for this post! I didnt think about removing the boot drive to setup the raid first. When I looked into the BIOS, it only had one option for RAID so I thought it would apply it across all attached discs so I exited out. Even if this is the case, your suggestion will work. Will try it out tonight. Thanks!